# Вычисление списка чисел Фибоначчи рекурсией

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

Через рекурсию вычисляю числа Фибоначчи.

Хочу, чтобы возвращался список чисел Фибоначчи длины `n`, но в результате получаю ошибку:

```py
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

***Код:***

```py
def fib(n):
    s = []
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    else:  
        s.append(fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))
        return s
```

Не понимаю, почему происходит так. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fib(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

print(fib(5))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ваш код возвращает *число*, а автору нужен *список*.

Comment: @nomnoms12, на мой __субъективный__ вкус, лучше использовать эту более симпатичную и понятную реализацию и `list comprehension`:  `[fib(x) for x in range(1, 5+1)]`

Comment: @Denis, в идеале стоило бы закешировать вычисление чисел Фибоначи ([смотрите пример в документации...](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache))

Comment: @MaxU Только что, благодаря Вам, узнал, что так можно :) Думал, что для этого стоит реализовывать Фибоначчи динамически (но все равно динамический вариант лучше, как мне кажется)

Answer (score 2):

1. При каждом рекурсивном вызове Вы обнуляете список инструкцией `s = []`.
2. В базовом случае Вы возвращаете число, а должны список (*отсюда и ошибка*).

Исходя из этого, и генерация нового числа будет выглядеть иначе.

***Пример:***

```py
def fib(n: int) -> list:
    if n == 1:
        return [1]
    elif n == 2:
        return [1, 1]

    li = fib(n-1)
    li.append(li[-1] + li[-2])
    return li

print(fib(5))
```

***stdout***

```py
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение!

Answer (score 0):

Рекурсия не самый выгодный вариант расчёта ряда Фибоначчи.
В питоне можно рассчитать ряд одной строкой и проще через число фи. Вот посмотрите здесь подробнее - https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/5f29407e182c181badd39e4b/62a1115d739e40251a09805a

См. пункт 3 Алгоритм через "золотое число" фи.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Я оставил описание